# In the oc, what is the difference between _xxx and self->_xxx

Tags: objective-c, c

I know the difference between `self.xxx` and `_xxx`
But I don't understand the difference between `self->_xxx = yyy` and `_xxx = yyy`

Is it only a matter of writing in ObjC and C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Addition to @iosdude Answer:

"
When accessing an ivar there is no difference between `self->_ivar` and `_ivar` in terms of resulting compiled code.
"

Dereferencing an iVar `->` can be useful for "weakStrongDance" [Example](http://When%20accessing%20an%20ivar%20there%20is%20no%20difference%20between%20self-%3E_ivar%20and%20_ivar%20in%20terms%20of%20resulting%20compiled%20code.)
Where you want to dereference the iVar of a `weakSelf` instead of `self` `iVar`.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing an ivar there is no difference between `self->_ivar` and `_ivar` in terms of resulting compiled code.

Only use case I can think of where it matters is if you have another local or global variable with the same name in the same scope, and you want to use the ivar.

Comment: Even if I have another local or global variable with the same name in the same scope   But Xcode should be able to give me an error.....

Comment: @Graliet by Default Xcode will only trigger a warning in this case, unless you set a flag to treat warnings as errors.